# Is this an Immanuel Kant quote?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, kant, reality

*You can imagine the perfect chair in your mind but you cannot build the perfect chair.*

Or something very similar.  I believe that is Kant but I cannot find any reference to the quote anywhere.  Any one have some ideas?

Comment: You might have better luck asking in the [Philosophy Café](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/538/philosophy-cafe).  As it stands, this sort of question doesn't really work on the Stack Exchange network.  But I think if you asked about the quote or the sentiment (and could dig up some references somehow) this has the makings of an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Kant's idea of [Noumena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noumenon). For example:

> We then realise that not only are the
>   drops of rain mere appearances, but that even their round
>   shape, nay even the space in which they fall, are nothing in
>   themselves, but merely modifications or fundamental forms of
>   our sensible intuition, and that the transcendental object
>   remains unknown to us.

Alternatively, you may be thinking of the [Theory of Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms) associated with Plato.